# Passing object field ByRef causes it to be set, even if it's not changed

Tags: vb.net

Working with a 3rd party API in .NET.  Their API doesn't handle DBNull well, so I have created a little helper function called "SetStringValue" that looks like this:

```
Public Sub SetStringField(ByRef _DestinationField As Object, ByVal _Value As Object)
    If Not TypeOf _Value Is DBNull Then
        _DestinationField = _Value
    End If
End Sub
```

In my main code, I have a line like this:

```
SetStringField(SomeAPIObject.Fields(SOME_FIELD_ENUM), DataRow.Item("SourceValue"))
```

If you follow the flow of the code when it hits a DBNull, it never runs the line:

```
_DestinationField = _Value
```

Yet, "SomeAPIObject" reports that the field was set and dirty, even though I never did.  It's like .NET is setting the passed argument with the original value, just because I passed it as reference.

Is that expected?  Any way to avoid that?

Comment: Not sure to understand correctly what is the problem, but you can simply start the debugger, set a breakpoint in this function and check what is the code flow and the value of the variables passed to the function

Comment: Instead of DBNull what do they support? If they support Nothing then your function wouldn't need to have a ByRef parameter and just have a return value that returns _Value or Nothing. Btw: Usually, an underscore indicate a class variable, not a parameter.

Comment: Come to find out, the 3rd party API is marking a field dirty if I even call the .Fields property to get a value.  It's an error in their code that I'll have to use dvmill's solution to get around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that the `apiObject.Fields(...)` call is what's turning your object into a dirty, dirty, dirty, dirty, filthy, dirty, object?

Rewrite your function:

```
Public Sub SetStringField(o as Øbject, e as Enüm, v As Øbject)
    If Not TypeOf v Is DBNull Then
        o.Fields(e) = v
    End If
End Sub
```

Then call it like:

```
SetStringField(SomeAPIObject, SOME_FIELD_ENUM, DataRow.Item("SourceValue"))
```

Or some crap. More umlauts.

Comment: You have a weird keyboard setting.

Comment: Dave, this took care of it.  I love you even more than I did before.